# How to run cmd windows netsh command using python?

Tags: python, windows

I am trying to run the following netsh command on Windows 7 however It returns incorrect syntax

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.system("netsh interface ipv4 set interface ""Conexão de Rede sem Fio"" metric=1")
The syntax of the file name, directory name or volume label is incorrect.


1
>>>
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`os.system`is a very old choice and not really recommended.

Instead you should consider `subprocess.call()` or `subprocess.Popen()`.

Here is how to use them:

If you don't care about the output, then:

```
import subprocess
...
subprocess.call('netsh interface ipv4 set interface ""Wireless Network" metric=1', shell=True)
```

If you do care about the output, then:

```
netshcmd=subprocess.Popen('netsh interface ipv4 set interface ""Wireless Network" metric=1', shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE )
output, errors =  netshcmd.communicate()
if errors: 
   print "WARNING: ", errors
 else:
   print "SUCCESS ", output
```

Comment: I was testing again, I see my problem are latin characters, I removed them then It worked. Do you know any issue while running commands with latin characters?

Comment: hmm ... no, usually I avoid non ascii characters in programming. For a few reasons, and mostly because the windows terminal is dumb.

Comment: @dextervip, did you check if your code works within a script? add the line # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- in the beginning of your script. AND MAKE sure your editor saves the document like that. Finally, do give a try to my suggestion, os.system will bite you again when you want to do complicated stuff.

Comment: Well I will be working with non ascii characters, thank you :)