# Enabling Wifi In monitor mode Using Python in Windows Platform

Tags: python, windows, wifi

Can any one help in enabling wifi monitor mode in windows using python scripting.
Suggest Modules available for the same purpose compatible with Windows 7 and Python 3.6

For Linux it done using the follwoing code

```
iface = "wlan"
os.system('iwconfig ' + iface + ' mode monitor')
```

Please let me know if any thing else is to be mentioned for more clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent of "iwconfig" for windows is "netsh"

So your command should look something like:

```
import subprocess
...
subprocess.call('netsh trace start capture=yes', shell=True)
```

You can find all the details there:
[How to run cmd windows netsh command using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381733/how-to-run-cmd-windows-netsh-command-using-python)

Comment: Thanks Luc. Will this work as a monitor mode to capture all the packets available ??

Comment: If your wifi card support the monitor mode, Yes. You just need to pass the appropriate setting through netsh. Otherwise the problem is in your card.

Comment: can you please assist me in capturing all  the available packets around.

Comment: If you have another question, please open a new thread, so others would be able to help as well

Comment: you can use ```netsh wlan show wirelesscapabilities``` and look for `Network monitor mode                        : Supported` to verify if you card suport monitor mode or not